# F# AsyncSeq speed issue

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

I am trying out AsyncSeq and I am confused by a speed issue I am having. Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VwziUA) of the code below.

```
open System
open FSharpx.Control

let rec numbers n x = asyncSeq {
    yield n
    //printfn "%A" n
    do! Async.Sleep(1)
    if (n + 1 = x) then
        yield n + 1
    else
        yield! numbers (n + 1) x
}

Async.Sleep(300) |> Async.RunSynchronously
for i in [0..300] do printfn "%A" i

numbers 0 300
|> AsyncSeq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The top loop finishes clearly in a shorter amount of time. While the bottom async sequence takes longer. Is this normal? or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing whatever overhead using AsyncSeq involves. What exact times are you getting for each case, and what do you expect to see instead?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/f25319b46bc3242a2849) there will already be a overhead caused by just using Async-Workflows (if you run it more than once it will always be > 20ms on my system) and that is not counting the overhead the recursive part here might cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous sequences have been designed for writing computations that involve some *asynchronous waiting* such as disk or network I/O. For this reason, it is quite sensible to expect some overhead when using `asyncSeq` - in the typical use case, this is not very significant compared to the overhead of the asynchronous operations.

I had a quick look at your example and most of the overhead here is actually coming from `Async.Sleep(1)` - this uses `System.Threading.Timer` internally (to schedule the continuation to be called in a thread pool).

On my machine, the following code (with `Async.Sleep`) takes about 4.6 seconds:

```
let rec numbers n x = asyncSeq {
    yield n
    do! Async.Sleep(1) // (sleep)
    if (n < x) then yield! numbers (n + 1) x }

numbers 0 300
|> AsyncSeq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

But when you drop the `Async.Sleep` call (line marked `(sleep)`), the computation takes just 30ms, which is pretty much the same as the following `for` loop:

```
for i in [0..300] do 
  printfn "%A" i
```

Now, if you add asynchronous sleeping to the `for` loop, it takes 5 seconds too:

```
for i in [0..300] do 
  Async.Sleep(1) |> Async.RunSynchronously
  printfn "%A" i
```

This is not too surprising - if you replaced asynchronous sleeping with `Thread.Sleep`, then it would run faster (but synchronously). So, in summary:

- There is certainly some overhead of `asyncSeq` itself, but it is not that big
- Most of the overhead in your example comes from asynchronous sleeping using `Async.Sleep`
- This is quite realistic model of typical uses of asynchronous sequences - they are designed for writing computations that do some asynchronous waiting
- Measuring performance overhead using toy examples like `Async.Sleep` can be misleading :-)

Comment: great answer (of course) - but just as a quick question/remark: does it really take 5 **seconds** on your machine do run 300 `Sleep(1)`?

Comment: Yes, it does take 5 seconds. I was surprised too - it seems the `Timer` is pretty slow :-). When I do `async { return () } |> Async.RunSynchronously` in the loop, it takes almost no time...

Comment: Even adding `do! Async.SwitchToNewThread()` still keeps this to around 60ms for 300 iterations.

Comment: wow I have to check that out later, because the same code just inside `async` does take only about 20-30ms more